# Lines don't show on my canvas, using C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

So, my gui is divided into two halves, both using the same class times two, since both do the exact same thing: Each draw their own graph, so they can compare two different processes.

So in order to figure out how to draw the graph, I wanted to first do something simple, and just hard-code two lines in. Note that I do not use XAML, I am postponing this until I am fluid enough with C#, and I am used to making GUIs that way. Another thing I did was to change the Canvas' colour, and, as it turns out, it is, where it is suppose to be. Anyway, what I did was just create  a line like this:

```
Line lne = new Line();
lne.X1 = 10;
lne.X2 = 130;
lne.Y1 = 10;
lne.Y2 = 100;
graphCanvas.Children.Add(lne);
```

In the entirety of my GraphComparisonClass it looks like this:

```
public class AlgorithmRuntimeView: StackPanel
{
    public GraphComparison() 
    {

        this.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        this.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        Canvas graphCanvas = new Canvas();
        graphCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
        graphCanvas.Height = 400;
        graphCanvas.Width = 390;

        Line lne = new Line();
        lne.X1 = 10;
        lne.X2 = 130;
        lne.Y1 = 10;
        lne.Y2 = 100;
        graphCanvas.Children.Add(lne);

        Line lnje = new Line();
        lne.X1 = 150;
        lne.X2 = 130;
        lne.Y1 = 105;
        lne.Y2 = 10;
        graphCanvas.Children.Add(lnje);

        this.Children.Add(algorithmListMenu);
        this.Children.Add(graphCanvas);

    }
    public void drawPoint(int time, int size)
    {
        //convert time and size to coordinates
    }
}
```

I'd expect the lines to be located on the canvas, they are not. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong, or did I do some minor mistake? I'd assume that I am using the coordinates wrong, but I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the stroke & thickness:

eg

```
myLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
```

Comment: doco is your friend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview

Comment: it works, thanks! (short question, up left is 0/0, isnt it?)

Comment: 0/0 yes i think so